# Unable to connect to SQL Server using windows authentication mode through PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, scheduled-tasks, windows-authentication

I have only one option to connect to SQL Server using Windows authentication mode. When I am trying to connect it through SQL Management studio it is working properly. Same thing I am trying to do using PowerShell using following code:

```
$Path = 'D:\'
write "Starting script --------" | Out-File $Path\output.txt
$SQLServer = 'server_name,1111'
$Database = 'db_name'

try {
    $Connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection
    $Connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$SQLServer;Integrated Security=$true;Initial Catalog=$Database"
    $Connection.Open()

    Write-Host 'Open database connection'
    write "Open database connection" | Out-File $Path\output.txt -Append
    }
catch {
    Write-Host 'An error occurs'
    write "error opening connection: $_" | Out-File $Path\output.txt -Append
}
finally {
    ## Ensure closing the connection to release the resource / free memory
    $Connection.Close()

    Write-Host 'Close database connection'
    write "Close database connection" | Out-File $Path\output.txt -Append
}
```

It is working properly when run it manually but it is showing following error when I schedule it in Windows Task Manager. In scheduler it is schedule with same user through which I have connect to server and same user is having rights to connect to DB.

> error opening connection: Exception calling "Open" with "0"
> argument(s): "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'."

[image]

Security option. I have just marked some part of the username for security purposes

Can anyone help me what wrong I am doing here?

Comment: _In scheduler it is schedule with same user through which I have connect to server and same user is having rights to connect to DB._ Share the screenshot of the task > security options section.

Comment: I am unable to see task > security option in task schedule. Under task I am getting General, Trigger, Action Conditions, Settings and History options

Comment: It on the fisrt tab, a section called security options.

Comment: @VinkeshShah Windows Authentication works fine. The error suggests you used the wrong account settings for the task and probably *didn't* specify an actual domain account, which means your script is running as an anonymous user

Comment: Have you tried unticking the "Do not store password" checkbox? Among other things ticking that will prevent it from loading the user's registry hive and a whole bunch of functionality breaks.

Comment: @salmanA Attached screenshot

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, I have tried but it does not allow me save task without that option

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I scheduled job on the server with the same user with domain who is having access on DB.

Comment: Does this user account have the "Logon as batch job" right?

Comment: Assuming SQL Server is on another machine, it does not know about the users on the task scheduler machine.

Comment: @SalmanA, Yes, SQL Server on another machine.

Comment: The screenshot you posted clearly shows you selected `do not store password. The task will only have access to local computer resources`. Attempts to connect to other machines will be anonymous, if they're allowed at all

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, what option do I have. It is not allowing me to save the scheduler without that option.

Comment: It does - you just have to enter the password. Clear the checkbox and enter the password

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I have tried that but after entering password it shows error as "An error has occurred for task DB_Connection. Error message: The following error was reported: 2147943712" and not allowing me to save it.

Comment: Did you google that error? There are identical questions already